# How to Draw an ellipse: half is continuous, half is dashed

Tags: mesh, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an ellipse, I want half is continuous line, half is dashed line.

If I use scripts, what should I do?

Thank you !
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

op = bpy.ops
me = op.mesh

op.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
me.select_all()
me.subdivide(number_cuts=2)

d = bpy.context.object.data
verts = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(d).verts

for v in verts:
    if v.co.x > 0: v.select = True
    else:          v.select = False
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(d)

me.select_nth(nth=4, offset=-2)
me.delete(type='VERT')
```

You can do *nth=3* if you want smaller dashes.

[image: Dashed]